# How can I get into the House of Respite?

Tags: the-witcher-3

While back tracking old quests, I stumbled upon this place in Velen:

[image]

The guards won't let me in, and there's no real dialog with them. The whole place is surrounded with an unpassable fence.

This is the location in the World Map:

[image]

How can I get inside? I have completed all the secondary quests and contracts already (After taking the screenshots), and I'm very far in the main quest, so pretty sure it's not something in there. (Final Preparations quest)

Answer (score 6):

You need to be wearing Nilfgaardian armor. I think the Nilfgaardian courtiers costume you got in Vizima also works. Just as long as you appear to be a Nilfgaardian.

Comment: Sounds too easy, but I'll give it a try. Hope I kept that costume. Thanks!

Comment: It is easy because there isn't much to do inside!

Comment: I mean it like "too good to be true", I don't expect much since I'm way over levelled for that area anyway. (Just bored with main quest, so looking for everything else before finishing the game. :))

Comment: Update: it didn't work with ordinary Nilfgaardian armor, and I lost the elegant clothing that I had. Will try to look for it again though.

Comment: Just testing here the Nilfgaardian armor from the Quartermaster at Crow's Perch works as does the courtier's clothes. There is a sign at the gate saying 'officers only' so presumably high class armor is required. One save with the main game complete seems to let me in regardless.

Comment: Weird, maybe I wasn't wearing a full set. Will give this a try, thanks! :)